# Why can i not add a new link to the main menu?

Tags: routes

I cannot for the life of me figure why i cannot add a new link to the main menu?!

the error i get reads

```
'The path 'events' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.'
```

i have tried numerous work arounds, tricks, checked permission, menu modules, everything i can think of but i cannot understand why.

am clueless, does anyone here know?

Comment: The path has to exist then only you can add it as link, have you created the path **events**.

Comment: Try create a menu with name "test" and link it to home page by adding <front> as its path. Check it

Comment: Woverine is right, 'Path has to exist'. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Modules list `/admin/modules` and make sure the **Path** module is enabled.

Comment: nothing is working. i think it's related to some modules, conflicting

Comment: very very very frustrated

Comment: Sorry, it is true, Wolverine was right. 'The path has to exist' you can't just arbitrarily create menu links. could've swore you could!,